# Как сделать выпадающее меню в данной ситуации?

Tags: html, css

Пробовал разными путями сделать выпадающее меню, но все никак не выходит. Помогите ньюфагу пожалуйста. Снизу скинул код.
вот фрагмент с index.html

```
</div>
    <nav class="tm-main-nav">
    <ul class="tm-main-nav-ul">
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#ward" class="tm-nav-item-link">О палате</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#applicants" class="tm-nav-item-link">Претендентам</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#members" class="tm-nav-item-link">Членам палаты</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#registry" class="tm-nav-item-link">Реестр</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#patrial" class="tm-nav-item-link">Гражданам</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#training" class="tm-nav-item-link">Обучение</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#contact" class="tm-nav-item-link">Контакты</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

вот фрагмент с style.css

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .tm-main-nav {
        display: flex; 
        justify-content: space-between; ;
    }
    .tm-main-nav > ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 15px 30px 15px 40px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .tm.main.nav > ul li{
        position: relative;
        border-right: 1px solid #c7c8ca;
    }
    .tm.main.nav > ul li > a i.fa{
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 12px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .tm.main.nav > ul li:first-child{
        border-right: 1px solid #b2b3b5;
    }
    .tm-top-column { 
        position: absolute; 
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Вот так выглядит код, который Вы сбросили: https://take.ms/fEJl3.  Что откуда должно выпадать, непонятно

Comment: Зеленый еще) Могу полностью скинуть для общей наглядности)

Comment: Давайте. Заодно, опишите подробнее, как должно работать

Comment: в комментарии не могу прикрепить свои файлы, как быть?

Comment: Сделайте архив и загрузите например, сюда: https://fex.net/

Comment: вот ссылка с полный проектом, не получается сделать выпадающие окна на каждую кнопку. https://fex.net/s/d0a8c4n

Comment: так вы даже и не пытались сделать выпадашки ...их же нету в разметке

Comment: да вы правы, их нету, я их снес. Я просто не понимаю как это сделать.

Comment: между `LI` поместите `div` и в css напишите что `li` `relative` а этот `div` `absolute` `top:100%;` `left:0;` ширину и высоту т.е `min-height`

Answer (score 1):

CSS не совсем подходит для динамического изменения элементов, куда лучше с этим справляется JavaScript. Пришлось немного изменить структуру HTML-документа, но я решил твою проблему в несколько шагов:
   1) Создал файл script.js рядом с index.html
   2) Вписал туда следующий код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navigationItem').click(function(){
        var dropMenu = $(this).next();
        if (dropMenu.is(':visible')){
            dropMenu.slideUp();
        }
        else {
            dropMenu.slideDown();
        }
    });

    $('.submenuItem').click(function(){
        var dropMenu = $(this).parent();
        dropMenu.slideUp();
    });
});
```

3) Подключил скрипт к index.html в конце документа перед закрывающим тегом

```
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src = "script.js"></script>
</body>
```

P.S. Вот такая структура получилась у моего меню:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class = "navigationItem" href="#">Пункт меню 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class = "navigationItem" href="#">Пункт меню 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class = "navigationItem" href="#">Пункт меню 3(выпадающее)</a>
            <div class="navigationDrop"> 
                <a class = "submenuItem">Пункт подменю 1</a>
                <a class = "submenuItem">Пункт подменю 2</a>
                <a class = "submenuItem">Пункт подменю 3</a>
                <a class = "submenuItem">Пункт подменю 4</a>
                <a class = "submenuItem">Пункт подменю 5</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

P.S.S. Не заключай тег `<nav>` в тег `<div>`, nav вполне себе самостоятельный и респектабельный тег